OpenMP parallel for is substantially slower than sequential
I am running a simulation of random events happening in accordance with a given set of probabilities, until n events are hit, and repeating for as many iterations as desired. When I run this sequentially, it finishes a small test set of 24 iterations in 5 seconds. When I set a higher number of threads (16), the time involved becomes 55 seconds. I made these comparisons using time bash -c "...".
I am sorry for asking another one of these questions, but I have been searching for a solution for several hours now. I think the problem has to be some sort of race condition, but I just cannot seem to figure out on what. Variables target, n_probabilities and probabilities should all be private to the thread, and the majority of the time is spent between the print statements 'Started thread %d' and 'Finished thread %d'. This suggests to me that mutation_iterations[i] = simulate_iteration(target, n_probabilities, probabilities); then has to be the offending line, and mutation_iterations is a shared variable, but it should only be accessed a single time per thread so I don't see how it could cause this much of a speed drop.
However, looking at gprof output I don't really see an unusual amount of time spent on the function in question (although the 6.15 for main seems weird to me, as it is not the actual runtime):
Flat profile:

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name    
 98.86      6.08     6.08       24   253.33   253.33  simulate_iteration
  0.98      6.14     0.06                             _init
  0.16      6.15     0.01                             main

Admittedly this is my first time reading gprof, so I may be reading this entirely wrong. But as I see it, my program seems to be running for 49 seconds longer than gprof says it should, and I cannot figure out where this comes from.
The offending code:
    int **mutation_iterations = malloc(iterations * sizeof(int *)); 
    srand(0); // Set random number seed

    #pragma omp parallel shared(mutation_iterations) 
    {
        int target = desired_mutations;
        int n_probabilities = simulation_size;

        double probabilities[simulation_size];
        for (int i = 0; i < simulation_size; i++) {
            probabilities[i] = simulation_set[i].probability;
        }

        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
                mutation_iterations[i] = NULL;
                printf("Started thread %d\n", i);
                mutation_iterations[i] = simulate_iteration(target, n_probabilities, probabilities);
                printf("Finished thread %d\n", i);
        }
    }


The simulate_iteration(...) function:
int * simulate_iteration(int target, int n_probabilities, double probabilities[]) {
    int *counts = calloc(n_probabilities, sizeof(int));

    int total = 0;
    while (total < target) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n_probabilities; i++) {
            double rand_val = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;
            if (rand_val < probabilities[i]) {
                counts[i]++;
                total++;
            }
        }
    }

    return counts;
}

I must be overlooking something but I just can't see what. Any and all help would be much appreciated.

Consider putting together a [mcve].

You call rand from multiple threads. That function is not typically thread-safe.. Note that lack of thread-safety leads to cache-line bouncing which reduces performance. Broken code is often slow code, too

@RetiredNinja Sorry, I forgot about that. I'll put one together for the answer.

@Homer512 That is exactly it, the seed of rand was the race condition, thanks so much.

You may want the thread safe version: rand_r. Under glibc, it uses an LCG and is a bit faster as rand calls random. Also, erand48 might be better for floating point. See: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/drand48.html

Turns out I was overlooking a contention in rand(), thanks @Homer512 for pointing it out. I ended up using rand_r and that fixed it.
For anyone trying to do something similar, here is a minimum reproducible sample of the null mutational model I was making with the fix included:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <csv.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <pthread.h>


int * simulate_iteration(unsigned int c_iteration, int target, int n_probabilities, double probabilities[]) {;
    int *counts = calloc(n_probabilities, sizeof(int));

    int total = 0;
    while (total < target) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n_probabilities; i++) {
            double rand_val = (double) rand_r(&c_iteration) / RAND_MAX;
            if (rand_val < probabilities[i]) {
                counts[i]++;
                total++;
            }
        }
    }

    return counts;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int iterations = 24;
    int **mutation_iterations = malloc(iterations * sizeof(int *)); 

    #pragma omp parallel shared(mutation_iterations) 
    {
        unsigned int gen_seed = 0;
        int target = 500;
        int n_probabilities = 500;

        double probabilities[500];
        for (int i = 0; i < n_probabilities; i++) {
            probabilities[i] = (double) rand_r(&gen_seed) / RAND_MAX / 10;
        }

        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
                mutation_iterations[i] = NULL;
                mutation_iterations[i] = simulate_iteration(i, target, n_probabilities, probabilities);
        }
    }
    
    // Print the results
    printf("gene");
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        printf("\titer_%d", i);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < 500; j++) {
        printf("%d", j);
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            printf("\t%d", mutation_iterations[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) free(mutation_iterations[i]); 
    free(mutation_iterations);

    return 0;

}



You are still calling rand() inside a parallel section. It's still broken, just less noticeable since the total number of invocations is lower. To fix it, you need a random number generator that has its state either thread-local or managed via explicit variables, e.g. the ones in GSL or the rand48_r family of functions

Sorry, I fixed it in the problem in my code and then proceeded to make the exact same mistake in the example. It's fixed now, and output is reproducible as it should be. Thanks for pointing it out.
